# Rails Assets Precompilation Issue on CI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, continuous-integration, jasmine, sprockets

Rails 4.1.6, Ruby 2.1. We use CircleCI, and so far it's been working great. On development, our app runs fine, but today an issue cropped up on CircleCI and I don't know how to fix the problem. Could someone help?

I updated our gems yesterday, but we didn't have any issues until today (perhaps there was some caching going on?). I've rebuilt the build again and again (also selecting the option to clear the cache, but still no success), and the error persists.

I believe all of the tests pass, but here is where the error starts:

```
I, [2014-10-11T04:14:07.529348 #9596]  INFO -- : Writing /home/ubuntu/my-app-name/public/assets/jasmine/grunt/templates/SpecRunner-af60bb7e74338e42129e060a5ef78fcc.html
rake aborted!
NameError: undefined local variable or method `jasmine_version' for #<#<Class:0x00000002b8b1e8>:0x0000000d8e6540>
  (in /home/ubuntu/my-app-name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rails-assets-jasmine-2.0.0/app/assets/templates/jasmine/src/templates/example_project_jasmine_tags.html.erb)
/home/ubuntu/my-app-name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rails-assets-jasmine-2.0.0/app/assets/templates/jasmine/src/templates/example_project_jasmine_tags.html.erb:1:in `block in singleton class'
/home/ubuntu/my-app-name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rails-assets-jasmine-2.0.0/app/assets/templates/jasmine/src/templates/example_project_jasmine_tags.html.erb:-5:in `instance_eval'
/home/ubuntu/my-app-name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rails-assets-jasmine-2.0.0/app/assets/templates/jasmine/src/templates/example_project_jasmine_tags.html.erb:-5:in `singleton class'
/home/ubuntu/my-app-name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rails-assets-jasmine-2.0.0/app/assets/templates/jasmine/src/templates/example_project_jasmine_tags.html.erb:-7:in `__tilt_5657380'
/home/ubuntu/my-app-name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb:170:in `call'
/home/ubuntu/my-app-name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb:170:in `evaluate'
/home/ubuntu/my-app-name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb:103:in `render'
/home/ubuntu/my-app-name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:197:in `block in evaluate'
/home/ubuntu/my-app-name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `each'
/home/ubuntu/my-app-name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `evaluate'
/home/ubuntu/my-app-name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:12:in `initialize'
/home/ubuntu/my-app-name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `new'
/home/ubuntu/my-app-name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `block in build_asset'
/home/ubuntu/my-app-name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:395:in `circular_call_protection'
/home/ubuntu/my-app-name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:373:in `build_asset'
/home/ubuntu/my-app-name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
/home/ubuntu/my-app-name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
/home/ubuntu/my-app-name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
/home/ubuntu/my-app-name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
/home/ubuntu/my-app-name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
/home/ubuntu/my-app-name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:16:in `initialize'
/home/ubuntu/my-app-name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `new'
/home/ubuntu/my-app-name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `build_asset'
/home/ubuntu/my-app-name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
/home/ubuntu/my-app-name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
/home/ubuntu/my-app-name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
/home/ubuntu/my-app-name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
/home/ubuntu/my-app-name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
/home/ubuntu/my-app-name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:211:in `block in find_asset'
/home/ubuntu/my-app-name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:257:in `benchmark'
/home/ubuntu/my-app-name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:210:in `find_asset'
/home/ubuntu/my-app-name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:119:in `block in compile'
/home/ubuntu/my-app-name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in `each'
/home/ubuntu/my-app-name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in `compile'
/home/ubuntu/my-app-name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/non-stupid-digest-assets-1.0.4/lib/non-stupid-digest-assets.rb:31:in `compile_with_non_digest'
/home/ubuntu/my-app-name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.1.4/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:70:in `block (3 levels) in define'
/home/ubuntu/my-app-name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:146:in `with_logger'
/home/ubuntu/my-app-name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.1.4/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:69:in `block (2 levels) in define'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace) bundle exec rake assets:precompile returned exit code 1bundle exec rake assets:precompile returned exit code 1bundle exec rake assets:precompile returned exit code 1bundle exec rake assets:precompile returned exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may have been an issue with updating our gems. We I did a gem update, the version of Jasmine Core was fixed at 2.0.0, whereas Jasmine was updated from 2.0.2 to 2.0.3. Of course, I did update a number of other gems, and I went through our Gemfile and removed some version specifications.

Additionally, in our circle.yml file, our `pre` tasks included:

```
bundle exec rake assets:clobber
bundle exec rake tmp:clear
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

These were originally added because of some earlier problems we were having. I removed these.

I am also guessing that CircleCI was using cached gems, so the problem didn't appear immediately.

Anyways, this appears to have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what's going on here, but it could be due to wrong gem groups in your Gemfile. Try taking the jasmine gem out of any groups such as `:development` or `:test` and placing it along with the gems required for all environments.